# Stripes 1.6 missing SpringInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, stripes

Just upgraded an application from Stripes version 1.5.7 to 1.6.0, but it seems Spring framework integration has been changed since Stripes 1.5.7.

I now get an error stating that the `SpringInterceptor` class is missing:

```
Could not find class [net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring.SpringInterceptor] specified by the configuration parameter [Interceptor.Classes]. This value must contain fully qualified class names separated  by commas.
```

This class is requested in `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>Interceptor.Classes</param-name>
   <param-value>net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring.SpringInterceptor</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Indeed this class is no longer present in package `net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring`.

I suppose my Stripes configuration in `web.xml` should reflect these changes but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: `SpringHelper.injectBeans(this, StripesFilter.getConfiguration().getServletContext());` seems to work though. Still wondering why the Spring interceptor is done away with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This form of Spring integration was deprecated in version 1.6.0 of Stripes (https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/browse/STS-633?filter=10230); you have to use the following instead:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>Extension.Packages</param-name>
    <param-value>net.sourceforge.stripes.integration.spring</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: After such a long time finally someone who has an answer.Thanks Tony! That did the trick.